# how do I use ifelse to group a range of variables

Tags: r

in my dataset, I have a variable called ref that ranges from 0-7. Each participant has a score. I would like to group it so that 0-3 is 'low' and 4-7 is 'high'.

So I tried to make a new variable and tried to use the ifelse function

```
control_vs_fast$refsplit <- (ifelse(control_vs_fast$reflection >= 0 & control_vs_fast$reflection <=3, 'low', ifelse(control_vs_slow$reflection >3, 'high', 'no')))
```

I was wondering if there's a different function I can use so that I don't have to have 'no' as I have no missing values.

Sorry if that was unclear, I'm an R noob :(

EDIT: thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try the code below

```
within(
  control_vs_fast,
  refsplit <- c("high","low")[(reflection <=3)+1]
)
```

or

```
within(
  control_vs_fast,
  refsplit <- ifelse(reflection <=3,"low","high")
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for this. I'm trying to understand both of the codes you sent. So I think I understand the second one. If anything is 3 and below, it's classed as low and anything above that is high. I'm just struggling to understand the first code.

Comment: @dquestions Yes, you got it!

Answer (score 2):

This is a place that `cut` works well.

```r
control_vs_fast <- data.frame(reflection = c(-1:5))
control_vs_fast
#   reflection
# 1         -1
# 2          0
# 3          1
# 4          2
# 5          3
# 6          4
# 7          5
```

By default, `cut` returns labels using mathematical notation of open/closed ends:

```r
cut(control_vs_fast$reflection, c(-Inf, 0, 3, Inf))
# [1] (-Inf,0] (-Inf,0] (0,3]    (0,3]    (0,3]    (3, Inf] (3, Inf]
# Levels: (-Inf,0] (0,3] (3, Inf]
```

We can remove labels and go with integers

```r
cut(control_vs_fast$reflection, c(-Inf, 0, 3, Inf), labels = FALSE)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
```

or define our own labels

```r
cut(control_vs_fast$reflection, c(-Inf, 0, 3, Inf), labels = c("no", "low", "high"))
# [1] no   no   low  low  low  high high
# Levels: no low high
as.character(cut(control_vs_fast$reflection, c(-Inf, 0, 3, Inf), labels = c("no", "low", "high")))
# [1] "no"   "no"   "low"  "low"  "low"  "high" "high"
```

Note that when `labels=FALSE`, all returned values are integers, otherwise they are `factor`s. If you need strings (and/or don't know what `factor`s are), then the last one with `as.character` gives you strings.

### Correction

But all of the above are incorrectly marking `0` as `"no"` instead of `"less"`. To work around this, here's a slightly longer alternative. If you use the integer variant, than simple reassignment works as-is; but if you want strings, then the `factor`s will present a small problem; I'll use the `as.character` variant here.

```r
control_vs_fast$refsplit <- as.character(cut(control_vs_fast$reflection, c(0, 3, Inf), labels = c("low", "high"), include.lowest = TRUE))
control_vs_fast
#   reflection refsplit
# 1         -1     <NA>
# 2          0      low
# 3          1      low
# 4          2      low
# 5          3      low
# 6          4     high
# 7          5     high
control_vs_fast$refsplit[is.na(control_vs_fast$refsplit)] <- "no"
control_vs_fast
#   reflection refsplit
# 1         -1       no
# 2          0      low
# 3          1      low
# 4          2      low
# 5          3      low
# 6          4     high
# 7          5     high
```

Explanation:

The problem is that the ranges in `cut` are either left-open (default) or right-open. The only way to get one of the bins both left-closed and right-closed is to make it the first range/bin and add `include.lowest=TRUE`. From here, anything less than 0 (if you have that) will be `NA`, meaning that it was not within one of the assigned bins.

From there, we use indexed-assignment based on those that are `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with reproducible data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(0:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE)

ifelse(x <= 3, 'low', "high")

#  [1] "low"  "low"  "high" "low"  "low"  "high" "high" "low"  "high"
# [10] "low"
```